# Output not written to textbox c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm new to programming in .net. For a first project I want to write data to a sql server database. It's a very basic program with one form, a few textboxes for input and one for output. The purpose of the program is to keep track of my training. I also have a textbox for output, the problem is that nothing appears in that textbox (except for "test"). I guess it's a simple problem, but I can't figure it out.

(As I've said, I'm new to .net programming, so if any of you guys could give tips for best-practice programming would be appreciated also).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Write_to_database
{
    public partial class WriteToDatabase : Form
    {
        public WriteToDatabase()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlServer sql = new SqlServer();
            WriteToOutput("test");
            sql.OpenSqlConnection();
            sql.WriteToTraining("20151231","10",10.0,5,5);
            sql.CloseSqlConnection();

        }


        public string WriteToOutput(string output)
        {
            this.tOutput.Text += output + "\r\n";
            return this.tOutput.Text.ToString();
        }




    }

    public class SqlServer : WriteToDatabase
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        public void OpenSqlConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                WriteToOutput("Connection to: " + "'Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;'" + " successful.");
            }
            catch
            {
                WriteToOutput("Connection to: " + "'Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;'" + " failed.");
            }
        }

        public void CloseSqlConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                con.Close();
                WriteToOutput("Connection to: " + "'Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;'" + " successfully closed");
            }
            catch
            {
                WriteToOutput("Connection to: " + "'Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;'" + " not closed.");
            }
        }

        public void WriteToTraining(string date, string lift, double weight, int reps, int week)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO LIFT_HISTORY VALUES(@date,@lift,@weight,@reps,@week)", con))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("weight", weight.ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("date", date.ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("week", week.ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("reps", date.ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("lift", date.ToString()));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                WriteToOutput("Data successfully written to database.");

            }
            catch
            {
                WriteToOutput("Data not written to database.");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Since you didn't show properties of your textbox, I'm assuming that your textbox is single line, while you should enable it's multiline capabilites (either from form designer or through properties) to show additional text added with newline charaters.

Comment: Also I think this is a bad class design to derive your database logic class from a class that inherits from Form. You should make your SqlServer class to stand on its own, rather than inherit from form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SqlServer class should not inherit from the WriteToDatabase class as the WriteToDatabase class inherits the Form class. What is actually happening in your code is that you create a new Form when you create you SqlServer class and the text box on that form is getting updated with the values. You can see this if you call the method sql.Show() after you have created a new instance of the SqlServer class.

The following code will update the values on the WriteToDatabase form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Write_to_database
{
    public partial class WriteToDatabase : Form
    {
        public WriteToDatabase()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    private void bWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlServer sql = new SqlServer();
        WriteToOutput("test");
        WriteToOutput(sql.OpenSqlConnection());
        WriteToOutput(sql.WriteToTraining("20151231", "10", 10.0, 5, 5));
        WriteToOutput(sql.CloseSqlConnection());

    }

    public void WriteToOutput(string output)
    {
        this.tOutput.Text += output + "\r\n";
    }
}

public class SqlServer
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
    public string OpenSqlConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            return "Connection to: " + "'Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;'" + " successful.";
        }
        catch
        {
             return "Connection to: " + "'Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;'" + " failed.";
        }
    }

    public string CloseSqlConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            con.Close();
            return "Connection to: " + "'Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;'" + " successfully closed";
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Connection to: " + "'Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=TRAINING;Integrated Security=SSPI;'" + " not closed.";
        }
    }

    public string WriteToTraining(string date, string lift, double weight, int reps, int week)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO LIFT_HISTORY VALUES(@date,@lift,@weight,@reps,@week)", con))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("weight", weight.ToString()));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("date", date.ToString()));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("week", week.ToString()));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("reps", date.ToString()));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("lift", date.ToString()));
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return "Data successfully written to database.";

        }
        catch
        {
            return "Data not written to database.";
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. This solved my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you try to add multiple lines to your `TextBox`, you should set the [`Multiline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your `TextBox` to `true`.

And I suggest to

- use [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `"\r\n"`
- use [`TextBox.AppendText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `tOutput.Text += ...`

Answer (score -1):

This is more simply written as:

```js
 public void WriteToOutput(string output)
        {
            this.tOutput.Text += output + "\r\n";
        }
```

There is no reason to return a string when it's output is to a textbox. Also ensure your textbox is enabled for multiple lines on client side.
Also I recommend prefixing the name of your textboxes with something of the nature of "txtOutput" so that when your codebase grows you don't confuse yourself or anyone scoping through your code as to what a particular control/object is.

Also I recommend throwing away sqlwriter and instead grab a version of entity framework. Entity framework and other object-relational mappers are what's actually used in industry because the opening and closing of sql - select statements become too tedious to manage.

Plus entity framework if you're using a smart environment like visual studio really helps when your debugging your own code and you need an at-a-glance error stack trace.

Plus learning entity framework gets you into understanding linq. Every newbie should be shoved in this direction I know I wish I was when I started coding in .net several years ago.

Comment: Learning an entire framework for something that's already (mostly) functional seems to be overkill at best.  EF is nice for an enterprise grade application, but this certainly doesn't appear to be what the OP is dealing with.  To add to that, EF and Linq also have a pretty heavy amount of overhead for something that appears to be a very basic application.

Comment: Your opinion is correct, however it's only addressing this question at a superficial level, my perspective is considering what is best in store for the developer. Keep in mind part of his question was asking for advice.

Comment: Thank you both for the response, I will look into the entity framework. Not for this project, but it's good to know, or at least have an understanding of what they use in the industry. Also, thanks for the tips, used them to improve my code :).

Comment: @hatsjie good luck my friend. Remember 100% focus is the key driving force to success in programming.